# is it possible to use SocketClientAccessPolicyProtocol.Http while in development using Cassini

Tags: silverlight, sockets, silverlight-4.0

I have 3 projects in a Visual Studio 2010 solution. A Console App that is acting as my socket server, a Silverlight Client that would like to consume data from said socket server, and a Web project that hosts the Silverlight client and a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file.

It seems to me that using `SocketClientAccessPolicyProtocol.Http` will not work as the Silverlight client would try and download the `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file over port 80 and not the port that Cassini is using for that debugging session.

I would rather not have to build a Policy Server, or more accurately, I would rather not have to open up port 943 in addition to 4502-4534 that I'm currently allowing.

Is it possible to use the Http option for retrieving the `accesspolicyfile.xml` in this case?